# Почему внутри функции Python не работает вложенный if

Tags: python, if

Я пытаюсь внутри функции использовать вложенный if.

```
def login(req):
    if req == 'POST':
        username = 'username'
        if username == 'root':
            print("Correct username and password")
        else:
            print("Wrong username or password")
    login('POST')
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
if username == 'root':
                      ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Если тот же код использую без функции

```
req = 'POST'
if req == 'POST':
    username = 'username'
    if username == 'root':
        print("Correct username")
    else:
        print("Wrong username")
```

Все работает. Можете мне подсказать, в чём проблема. Ругается на отступы, но я их проверял. Код проверял в PyCharm и jupyter notebook. Результат тот же.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на отступы, может где путаница в пробелах/табуляциях. Потому что ошибка явно говорит, что проблема с отступами. И ваш пример отлично работает если все пробелы на своих местах https://ideone.com/VE9FXk

Comment: @Andrey Я отформатировал ваш код, попробуйте его скопировать, может быть что-то у вас получится.

Comment: Заменил табуляцию 4-я пробелами и заработало. Буду знать.